# Linking "Friends" with the account holders profile

Tags: sql, friend

I am designing an application where an account holder has "friends". How would I go about linking those friends to the original account holder? Would an efficient SQL table be something like:

```
AccountHolderID (varChar 20)
FriendsID (nText)
```

Comment: Is a Friend another user/account holder in your system?

Comment: yes, you are correct. I am thinking a FriendID would have to be a foreignKey (so it can't be nText), perhaps?

Comment: If it is assumed that each account holder can have one or more friends, and each friend can be associated with one or more account holders, then you need a many-to-many relationship. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192416/will-this-normalised-database-structure-permit-me-to-search-by-tags-as-i-intend/3192607#3192607) for an example of a many-to-many relationship in MySQL. Replace items with account holders, and tags with friends, and you have the basis for your schema. The web is full of tutorials on database relations.

Comment: Was your intention with making FriendsID an NTEXT field to store a string along the lines of "personid1, personid2, personid3"?  If so, you should understand that this would make queries involving this field very difficult to write and highly inefficient - you should avoid storing multiple values in a single field - it's not the database way!

Comment: yes, the intention was to say UserID1001 has a friend UserID2001, UserID3021, UserID3310 etc.

Answer (score 0):

We implement something similar--using a table to hold the friends...  Ours breaks down quite simply as a table of friends...

```
AccountHolderId( type)
FriendAccountHolderId ( type)
Created(datetime)  // useful for tracking when the friend was added
```

Both of the Id fields link back to the Accounts/Users table.

Comment: what datatype is your AccountHolderID & FriendAccountHolderID ? Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: We were using GUIDs in SQL Server.  (Wow, five years later!)