# Sql Statement construction

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi im trying to use Sql within MySql to sort some values and this is what I have:

Select from my table the rows where the value in column status equals online and the value in column tags equals museum, order them by name and in ascending order.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tech
 WHERE `STATUS` = 'online'
   AND `TAGS` = 'museum'
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

However what I need is this:

Select from my table the rows where the value in column status equals online **and there is this value in column tags that equals museum**, order them by name and in ascending order.

What I means is that right now in my DB my column tags only has one value per row, not very useful for using as tags. I want to change it so that the value in it would instead of "museum" be "museum 3d programming" and SQL check for a particular "word" in that string value.

Can it be done?

Comment: Full Text Search (FTS) is faster and more capable for text search/matching than LIKE ever will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM tech
 WHERE `STATUS` = 'online'
   AND `TAGS` like '%museum%'
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use [LIKE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tech 
    WHERE `STATUS` = 'online' 
        AND `TAGS` LIKE '%museum%' 
    ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Comment: @Marvin be sure to mark this as the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I can only mark one correct answer, im sorry, I voted it up but Jaime answered first.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `LIKE` and `%`. See [this site](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

So something like this

```
..AND `TAGS` like '%museum%'...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Tech
 WHERE `STATUS` = 'online'
   AND `TAGS` LIKE '%Museum%'
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating multiple tags in a single column, you should consider splitting the tags off into another table.  This is known as [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  It will make working with your data much easier, and will avoid having to perform `LIKE` searches, which can be very slow.

I answered a very similar question not so long ago, and included a sample table structure, some data, and some example queries.  The example given has three tables: `item`, `item_tag` and `tag`. `item` contains, well, items, and `tag` contains tags.  `item_tag` is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). It helps create a many-to-many relationship between the other two tables: each item may be associated many tags, and each tag may be associated with many items.  The junction table sits between the two, and contains a list of item-tag pairs:

[Will this (normalised) database structure permit me to search by tags as I intend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192416/will-this-normalised-database-structure-permit-me-to-search-by-tags-as-i-intend/3192607#answer-3192607)

You should also have a look at this MySQL tutorial:

[An Introduction to Database Normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Comment: Thank you this sounds something I should really study upon. I heard the term thrown around but haven't really looked it up yet.