# Join table with composite key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, composite-primary-key, join

Let's assume a generic join table FollowCompany between a User and a Company model, e.g.:

```
class FollowCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :company_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

end
```

It has a composite primary key [user_id, company_id].
It does NOT have an id column since a follow_company record is uniquely identified by [used_id, company_id]

Since I want to be able to treat the following relationship as a resource I made it RESTful:

routes.rb:

```
resources :follow_companies
```

This however causes a problem: These generated routes assume an :id key which I don't have.
 How do I tell rails that I'm actually using a composite key instead?

I can think of four solutions and I would like some input on which one is the best:

1. Don't make :follow_companies a resource. Instead, match the URLs with a two key pattern: e.g.: `match '/follow_companies/:user_id/:company_id/' => follow_companies#edit`
   This however is ugly because it's verbose and not RESTful.
2. Override the FollowCompany to_param method to contain both model ids, e.g.

   ```
   def to_param
    "#{user_id},#{company_id}"
   end
   ```

   This however is ugly because it seems like a hack and it has some nasty side effects
3. Add a primary key column to the follow_company table.
   This however is ugly because it adds redundancy. follow_company records are uniquely identified by [company_id, user_id]. No need for an additional key.
4. Download a composite-key gem and integrate it with my dev environment.
   This however is ugly because it's not a standard way and not compatible with other ruby code.

So, as you can see I couldn't come up with an elegant solution.
This seems like such a common scenario though that I can't be the first one to run into this. Virtually every app makes use of (restful) join tables.
What's a best practice of handling this?

Answer (score 2):

Number 3 has the advantage that your key would then be non-meaningful. While not super applicable to your case, if one of the key values needed to change for some reason, using a composite key would cause the URL to that resource to change. Creating a non-meaningful primary key means that URL would stay the same even after the data changes.

This also tends to be the "Rails way" of doing join tables.

Comment: +1  Yes and there are also many other good reasons to have a primary key that has no business value.  More info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8777574/631619

Comment: OK, granted. But doesn't that denormalize the table by introducing redundancy? Now I have to worry about duplicates such as a user following the same company twice. It's even possible to insert a (id,NULL,NULL) record indicating that nobody is following no company. To prevent nonsense like this I would have to use constraints. To me it seems that the additional id column adds a whole lot of complexity and headaches instead of making things easier. Is this really the preferred way?

Comment: Yes you could have (id, NULL, NULL) or duplicated, but surely you can validate for these things with validates_presence and validated_uniqueness :id1, scope: :id2

Comment: Where does  ` validated_uniqueness :id1, scope: :id2`  go when there is no model for the join table? Also, there doesn't seem to be any method named `validated_uniqueness` in the rails api.

Comment: @gwho `validates_uniqueness` is the Rails 2 syntax I believe. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness for the current way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that confident with ActiveRecord but why have a combined key? Surely what you are describing is a many_to_many join. So would this not work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follow_companies
  has_many :companies, through: :follow_companies
end

class FollowCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follow_companies
end
```

This means you could then route directly to the companies as a nested route like this:

```
resources :users do
  collection :follow_companies
end
```

This would give you routes like '/users/1/follow_companies' and in your controller your could do:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def follow_companies
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @companies = @user.companies
  end
end
```

Or something like that?