# Adding foreign key of type char in mysql

Tags: mysql, char, foreign-keys, column-types

i got a problem adding a foreign key in mysql (using phpmyadmin).

```
ALTER TABLE `production_x_country` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `pmdb_0.3.12`.`countries`(`iso_3166_1`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

based on some research and tests i've come to the conclusion that **`CHAR`** (that `production_x_country`.`country` field)  **is no valid foreign key field type** - though i did not find any hint to that assumption in the mysql docs.
if i change the column type to some other character type like `VARCHAR`, the procedure works.

**a similar question was "solved" here**, but that linked answer *wasn't about the type-problem* but about a country code being a primary key (what makes perfect sense to me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419235/4302731

---

table descriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `iso_3166_1` char(3) NOT NULL,  <----- primary key to be referenced to
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `countries` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`iso_3166_1`);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `production_x_country` (
  `production` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL   <----- column that should hold the foreign key
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

---

is there any solution (yes, i could go on using varchar, but thats not satisfying to me)? and most important: **is there any explanation**?

thank you for your help!

---

**solved** - see my own answer below

Answer (score 14):

solved!
this is not about the `char` field type but about the **collation**!

i like using UTF-8 mostly utf8_bin. so did i with the collation of my primary key:

```
`iso_3166_1` char(3) CHARACTER SET utf8
```

once i changed the primary key's collation to "latin1_swedish_ci" the foreign key application worked.
leads to the question: why is the collation of the primary key field (maybe also the foreign key field's, haven't checked that yet) important?

Comment: Man, you saved my day. Had the same problem, totally forgot about the collation!