# Error when creating foreign key of type CHAR with mysql workbench: Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have defined the following 2 tables:

**record_status**

**SHOW CREATE TABLE record_status**

```
CREATE TABLE `record_status` (  
  `record_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `status` char(6) NOT NULL,  
  `status_description` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_status_id`,`status`)  
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**user**

**SHOW CREATE TABLE user**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (  
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `handle` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `password` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `password_salt` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  `user_status` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),  
  KEY `usr_status_idx` (`user_status`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and I tried adding the foreign key user_status of type CHAR using mysql Workbench as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydatabase`.`user`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usr_status`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_status`)  
    REFERENCES `mydatabase`.`record_status` (`status`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

but I am getting the following error:

**Error**:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mydatabase.#sql-420_1b0' (errno: 150)

ALTER TABLE 'mydatabase'.'user'
ADD CONSTRAINT 'usr_status'
 FOREIGN KEY ('user_status')
 REFERENCES 'mydatabase'.'record_status'('status')
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION

SQL script execution finished: statements: 4 succeeded, 1 failed.
```

**Question**
My intention is to have the status column clearly show the current status for each user (ACTIVE, INACTV, DELETD) while still having the flexibility to join the record_status table with the user table using the record_status_id to find any rows with a given status for better performance.

*I found a similar post here*
[Adding foreign key of type char in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184211/adding-foreign-key-of-type-char-in-mysql)
which suggests to change my primary key's collation but, how would that affect my user table?

Will I have to change the collation to the user_status field in my user table as well? The user table will be queried every time a user logs in and I am concerned about performance or any constraints this may cause.

I also intend to add a foreign key for the status to a few other tables as well. I would just like to know how this affects performance, or does it add any constraints?

Any input regarding my design will also be appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you post actual `CREATE` statements for us [ideally unabridged `SHOW CREATE` output] we can see if we can recreate and solve the problem on our own systems.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the SHOW CREATE output details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing isn't actually related to collation (though collation can be a cause of the error you're experiencing under different circumstances).

Your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is failing because you don't have an index *individually* on `record_status.status`.  You have that column as part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY (record_status_id, status)`, but for successful foreign key constraint creation, both the referencing table and the referenced table must have indexes on *exactly* the columns used in the key relationship (in addition to the same data types).

Adding the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint implicitly creates the necessary index on the referencing table, but you must still ensure you have the corresponding index on the referenced table.

So given what you have now, if you added a single index on `record_status.status`, the constraint would correctly be created.

```
CREATE TABLE `record_status` (  
  `record_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `status` char(6) NOT NULL,  
  `status_description` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_status_id`,`status`),
  -- This would make your relationship work...
  KEY (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

However, I don't think that's the best course of action.  I don't see a need for the composite primary key on `(record_status_id, status)`, chiefly because the `record_status_id` is itself `AUTO_INCREMENT` and guaranteed to be unique. That column alone could be the `PRIMARY KEY`, while still adding an additional `UNIQUE KEY` on `status` to satisfy the foreign key constraint's indexing requirement. After all, it is not the *combination* of `record_status_id` and `status` which uniquely identifies each row (making a primary key)

```
CREATE TABLE `record_status` (  
  `record_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `status` char(6) NOT NULL,  
  `status_description` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  -- Primary only on record_status_id
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_status_id`),
  -- Additional UNIQUE index on status
  UNIQUE KEY (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

#### About the design -- eliminating `record_status_id`...

Without knowing how the rest of your application currently uses `record_status_id`, I can't say for sure if it required by your application code. But, if you wish to make the actual `status` value easily available to other tables, and it is merely `CHAR(6)`, it is possible that you actually have no need for `record_status_id` as an integer value.  After all, if the `status` string is intended to be unique, then it is perfectly capable of serving as the `PRIMARY KEY` on its own, without any auto-increment integer key.

In that case, your `record_status` table would look like below, and your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint would correctly be added to `users`.

```
CREATE TABLE `record_status` (
  -- Remove the auto_increment column!!
  `status` char(6) NOT NULL,  
  `status_description` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  -- Status is unique, and therefore can be the PK on its own
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Given this setup, [here's a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/771915) showing the successful creation of the tables and addition of the FK constraint.

You asked about performance implications of adding a status FK to other tables as well.  It's tough to speculate on that without knowing the purpose, but if other tables share the same `status` values, then it makes sense to create their FK constraints to link to it in the same say you're doing with `users`. And if that's the case, I would recommend doing it the same way, wherein the `status` column is `CHAR(6)` (or consider changing *all* of them to `VARCHAR(6)`).  The value of `record_status.status` still makes sense as the true primary key, and can be used as the FK in as many related tables as necessary.

In all but the most gigantic scale, there should be no appreciable performance difference between using an `INT` value and a `CHAR(6)/VARCHAR(6)` value as the foreign key. And the storage size difference between them is equally tiny. It isn't worth worrying about unless you must scale this to positively enormous proportions.