# MySql Foreign Key is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, localhost, primary-key

I am using xampp (localhost) and mysql to make a database for a project but i have a problem with foreign keys and i cant find my mistake when i am trying to create a student enrolment table this is the message i am getting:
**#1005 - Can't create table `X`.`studentenrolment` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

My Tables Code:

```
CREATE TABLE LOGINFO (
STUDENTNUMBER   NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL,
PASS CHAR(12),
CONSTRAINT LOGINFO_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTNUMBER));

CREATE TABLE LEADERS(
MODULESLEADER CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
LEADERSOFFICE CHAR(16) ,
LEADERSEMAIL  CHAR(16) ,
LEADERSPHONE numeric(4),
CONSTRAINT LEADERS_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (MODULESLEADER));

CREATE TABLE MODULES(
MODULESLEADER CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
MODULECODE CHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
MODULEDESCRIPTION CHAR(16) ,
LECTURESLOT CHAR (16),
LECTUREROOM CHAR(4) ,
CONSTRAINT MODULES_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (MODULESLEADER) REFERENCES LEADERS (MODULESLEADER),
CONSTRAINT MODULES_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (MODULESLEADER,MODULECODE));

CREATE TABLE STUDENTENROLMENT(
STUDENTNUMBER NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL,
MODULECODE CHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTNUMBER) REFERENCES LEADERS (STUDENTNUMBER), 
CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (MODULECODE) REFERENCES MODULES (MODULECODE), 
CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTNUMBER, MODULECODE));
```

I am trying  hours  to find what's the mistake with my syntax but i cant find it i've tried many other ways like:

```
CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT2_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (MODULECODE) REFERENCES MODULES (MODULECODE)
```

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTNUMBER) should specify to LOGINFO table.
2. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184211/adding-foreign-key-of-type-char-in-mysql) can help

It seems that this code doesn't cause an error:

```
CREATE TABLE LOGINFO (
  STUDENTNUMBER   NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL,
  PASS CHAR(12),
  CONSTRAINT LOGINFO_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTNUMBER));

CREATE TABLE LEADERS(
  MODULESLEADER CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  LEADERSOFFICE CHAR(16) ,
  LEADERSEMAIL  CHAR(16) ,
  LEADERSPHONE numeric(4),
  CONSTRAINT LEADERS_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (MODULESLEADER));

CREATE TABLE MODULES(
  MODULESLEADER CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  MODULECODE CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
  MODULEDESCRIPTION CHAR(16) ,
  LECTURESLOT CHAR (16),
  LECTUREROOM CHAR(4) ,
  CONSTRAINT MODULES_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (MODULESLEADER) REFERENCES LEADERS (MODULESLEADER),
  CONSTRAINT MODULES_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (MODULECODE, MODULESLEADER));



CREATE TABLE STUDENTENROLMENT
(
  STUDENTNUMBER NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL,
  MODULECODE CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_MODULES_MODULECODE_fk FOREIGN KEY (MODULECODE) REFERENCES MODULES (MODULECODE)
 ,CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_LOGINFO_STUDENTNUMBER_fk FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTNUMBER) REFERENCES LOGINFO (STUDENTNUMBER),
  CONSTRAINT STUDENTENROLMENT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTNUMBER, MODULECODE)
);
```