# List all items that have tag x and y assigned to it

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables.  An "item" table and a "tag" table.  Then I also have an "item_tag" table which ties the 2 together.

I want to make a query that lists all the items that have particular tags assigned to it.  So I would like the query to list all items that have tag x and tag y applied to it.

This is what I have come up with so far.. except that this will list any that match either tag id 148 or tag id 152.  If I make it say "AND" it shows no results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`item`)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `item_tag` ON `item`.`id` = `item_tag`.`fk_item_id`
WHERE `item_tag`.`fk_tag_id` = "152" OR `item_tag`.`fk_tag_id` = "148"
GROUP BY `item`.`id`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ids of the items that have all of the tags you want using this query:

```
SELECT fk_item_id
FROM item_tag
WHERE fk_tag_id IN (5,10,15)
GROUP BY fk_item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

And then just

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
WHERE id 
IN 
(
    SELECT fk_item_id
    FROM item_tag
    WHERE fk_tag_id IN (5,10,15)
    GROUP BY fk_item_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
)
```

You just have to modify the ids and the `3` which is the count of those ids.

When your table does not have `UNIQUE` constraint (it should have) and there can be the same tags in particular item you should modify the query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
WHERE id 
IN 
(
    SELECT fk_item_id
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT fk_item_id, fk_tag_id FROM item_tag ) someAlias
    WHERE fk_tag_id IN (5,10,15)
    GROUP BY fk_item_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
)
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT *)` is safer, in case a tag could be related more than once.

Comment: what does "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT *) mean?  also.. I assume the "IN" is the same as an having "OR"'s in the "WHERE" statement?

Comment: just ran into a problem with the query. check screenshot.. doesnt realy explain the error thougH :(

http://sensenich.bythepixel.com/error.gif

if i take out the "having count(disticnt) line the query runs.

Comment: The problem was with `DISTINCT`. When you remove it it work. However if in your table one item can be tagged more than once with the same tag you can make one more SELECT. I will edit my answer.

Comment: in all reality a tag should only be applied to an item at most once.  it wouldt make sense to apply the tag 'red' to a item more then once.  my backend currently doesnt realy allow it to happen.. but if a user clicks to fast, or refreshes to quickly the same tag could be added to one item.  is there a database way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes, you can add `UNIQUE` constraint. Like this `ALTER TABLE item_tag ADD UNIQUE(fk_item_id,fk_tag_id)`. It won't allow to appear the same pair (item, tag) twice.

Comment: Or you could make the `tag_id` and `fk_item_id` columns the primary key - a composite key.

Answer (score 3):

### Using JOINs:

```
 SELECT it.fk_item_id
   FROM ITEM i
   JOIN ITEM_TAG it1 ON it1.fk_item_id = i.id
                    AND it1.fk_tag_id = 148
   JOIN ITEM_TAG it2 ON it2.fk_item_id = i.id
                    AND it2.fk_tag_id = 152
```

### Using GROUP BY/HAVING COUNT:

```
  SELECT it.fk_item_id
    FROM ITEM_TAG it
   WHERE it.fk_tag_id IN (148, 152)
GROUP BY it.fk_item_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**Caveat emptor**:
The `GROUP BY/HAVING COUNT` version of the query is dependent on your data model having a composite key, unique or primary, defined for the two columns involved (`fk_item_id` and `fk_tag_id`).  If this is not in place, the database will not stop duplicates being added.  If duplicate rows are possible in the data, this version can return false positives because an `item_id` could have 2 associations to the `tag_id` 148 - which would satisfy the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`.

Comment: I'd prefer the method using JOIN, compare with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-appdevelopers "5. Favouring aggregation over joins"

Comment: @VolkerK: I lean towards JOINs myself, but the GROUP BY has been more popularly voted in the past on SO :/

Answer (score 2):

I put system in the tem table and programing language in tags. Using this query you have this result:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`item`)
INNER JOIN `item_tag` ON `item`.`id` = `item_tag`.`fk_item_id`
INNER JOIN `tag` ON `item_tag`.`fk_tag_id` = `tag`.`id`
WHERE `tag`.`desc` = 'Java' or `tag`.`desc` = 'C++'
```

Result:

```
1, 'Sistem A', 1, 1, 1, 'Java'
1, 'Sistem A', 1, 3, 3, 'C++'
2, 'Sistem B', 2, 1, 1, 'Java'
2, 'Sistem B', 2, 3, 3, 'C++'
```

In this case, system A and System B use Java and C++. To simplify use distinct clause

```
SELECT distinct item.desc
FROM (`item`)
INNER JOIN `item_tag` ON `item`.`id` = `item_tag`.`fk_item_id`
INNER JOIN `tag` ON `item_tag`.`fk_tag_id` = `tag`.`id`
WHERE `tag`.`desc` = 'Java' or `tag`.`desc` = 'C++'
```

Result:

```
System A
System B
```

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that this will model your tables ( you mention 3 tables but I only have 2 in this )

```
-- drop table item ;
-- drop table item_tag ;

create table item (
    id int not null auto_increment 
    , primary key ( id )
);
create table item_tag (
    fk_item_id int not null
,   fk_tag_id int not null
);

insert into item values ( 1 );
insert into item values ( 2 );
insert into item values ( 3 );

insert into item_tag values ( 1, 148 );
insert into item_tag values ( 1, 152 );

insert into item_tag values ( 2, 148 );

insert into item_tag values ( 3, 152 );

select i.id, a.fk_tag_id, b.fk_tag_id
from item i, item_tag a, item_tag b
where i.id = a.fk_item_id 
  and i.id = b.fk_item_id 
  and a.fk_tag_id = 148 
  and b.fk_tag_id = 152 
;
```

Produces the output

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | fk_tag_id | fk_tag_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |       148 |       152 | 
+----+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That limits him to two equal tags, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from item, item_tag a, item_tag b
where item.id = a.fk_item_id and a.fk_tag_id = 148 and
item.id = b.fk_item_id and b.fk_tag_id = 152;
```

Comment: Nope. He *has* to have both tags assigned to the item.

Comment: And what if he has more than two tags?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not trying to be a badass, I'm not smarter than you right now... ;)

Comment: I read the question as only needing two tags.  If he needs more than two, I'd have to think about it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

select * from item where item.id = itemtag.fk_item_id and item_tag.fk_tag_id = "152" or item_tag.fk_tag_id = "148" group by item.id

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `AND` now?