# Should I include user_id in multiple tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, normalization

I'm at the planning stages of a multi-user application where each user will only have access their own data. There'll be a few tables that relate to each other, so I could use JOINs to ensure they're accessing only their data, but should I include user_id in each table? Would this be faster? It would certainly make some of the queries easier in the long run.

Specifically, the question is about multiple tables containing the user_id field.

For example, each user can configure categories, items (in those categories), and sub-items against those items. There's a logical path from user, to sub-items through the other tables, but it would require 3 JOINs. Should I just include user_id in all the tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is a design decision in multi-tenant databases.  With "root" tables, obviously you **have** to have the user_id.  But in the non-"root" tables, you do have a choice when you are using surrogate PKs.

Say you have users with projects and projects with actions.  Projects obviously has to have a user_id, but if actions are tied to one and only one project, then the user_id is redundant, and also violates normal form, since if it was to move to another user's project (probably not likely in your use cases), both the project FK and the user FK would have to be updated.  Typically in multi-tenant scenarios, this isn't really a possible scenario, and so the primary key of every table is really a combination of tenant and a unique primary key "within" the tenant (which may also happen to be globally unique).

If you use natural keys extensively in your design, then clearly tenant+natural key is necessary so that each tenant's natural keys can be used.  It's only when using surrogates like IDENTITY or GUIDs or sequences, that this becomes an issue, since it is tempting to make the IDENTITY the PK, after all, it is unique by definition.

Having the user_id in all tables does allow you to do certain things in views to enhance security (defense in depth), giving you a little bit of defensive programming (in SQL Server you can restrict all access through inline table valued function - essentially parametrized views - which require the app to specify user_id on every "table" access), and also allows you to easily scale out to multiple databases by forklifting everything on shared keys.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) for some interesting insights.

(In a massively multi-parallel paradigm like Teradata, the PRIMARY INDEX determines the amp on which the data lives, so I would think that this is a must to stop redistribution of rows to the other amps.)

In general, I would say you have a tenantid in each table, it should be the first column in  the table, in most indexes and should be part of the primary key in most cases, unless otherwise justified.  Where possible, it should be a required parameter in most stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you use foreign keys to relate data between tables.  In many cases, this foreign key is the user id.  For example:

```
users
    id
    name

phonenumbers
    user_id
    phonenumber
```

So yes, that'd make perfect sense.

Comment: My question is whether or not to inlude it multiple tables, not just the one, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

If a category can only belong to one user then yes, you need to include the user_id in the category table. If a category can belong to multiple people then you would have a separate table that maps category IDs to user IDs. You can still do this if you have a one to one mapping between the two, but there is no real reason for it.

You don't need to include the user_id in further tables if you can guarantee that those child tables will always be accessed via joining to the category table. If there is a chance that you will access them independantly of the category table then you should also have the user_id on those tables.

Answer (score 2):

The extent to which to [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization-why-is-it-important) can be a difficult decision. One of the best StackOverflow answers on this topic ([Database Development Mistakes Made by App Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-app-developers)) warns against both (1) failing to normalize, and (2) over-normalizing.

You mention that it might be easier "in the long run" to repeat the same data in multiple tables (that is, not to normalize that data). Look at the "Not simplifying complex queries through views" topic in the previous link. If you use views effectively, you will only have to do the 3 join query once when writing the view and then you can use a query with no joins for most purposes.

Most developers tend to under-normalize because it seems simpler. Go ahead and normalize. Use views to simplify your daily queries. When your requiremens get more complex or you decide to add features, you will be glad that you put time into a relational database design.

Alternatively, depending on your toolset, you may want to use a [database abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+abstraction) layer that does the relational design under the covers while you manipulate higher level data object.

Answer (score 0):

if it is Oracle, then you would probably set up a fine grained security rule to do the joins and prevent certain activities based on the existence of the original user id... (SELECT INSERT UPDATE DELETE etc)

You would need a map between the logged in user and the user_id.  You could use uid, but then remember this umber may change if the database is reconstructed after some disaster...