# Does Sql Server cached compiled queries and execution plan across transactions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net, sqlclient

Folks,

I'm using the [best-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers) of prepared sql statements to execute many Inserts/Updates that vary by the same parameters.  I have two choices in my design: 1. all of the work gets done in a single transaction.  2. break-up the work into a number of transactions (not one per statement, but something that suits the concurrency of my environment).  If I opt for #2, will SQL take advantage of the cached compiled query/execution plan across transactions?  Or, because the query was made within a transaction, the life of the cache will be limited to the transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plans are unrelated to transactions. Or connections for that matter

That is, a plan can be shared by many txns and/or users and/or connections. And at different times if the plan is valid and still in cache

Answer (score 5):

The query cache is independent of transactions, so your queries will get cached regardless which option you choose.