# Database design + Table ids

Tags: relational-database, uniqueidentifier

I have often heard that numerically increasing numbers make good ids for static data tables. This has never made much sense to me - I would rather have meaningful ids.

To give you an example: say I am maintaining CurrencyInfo in a table. For USD, should the row identifier be 1 or USD? What is the preferred practice and why?

Do please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id that you are talking about is known as `surrogate key`. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

To know their advantages/disadvantages over `business keys`, take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys) here.

You can also take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers/621891#621891) at this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The unique identifier should NOT be something meaningful, it should be a unique identifier :) If your ID is meaningful NOW, it doesn't mean that it's meaningful later. Those things can always change..

So IMHO you should stick to a DBMS supported unique identifier. Those can be optimized etc..