# SQL query to find rows with at least one of the specified values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose you had two tables.  One called MOVIES:

- MovieId
- MovieName

Then another called ACTORS that contains people who appear in those movies:

- MovieId
- ActorName

Now, I want to write a query that returns any movie that contains ONE OR MORE of the following actors: "Tom Hanks", "Russell Crowe" or "Arnold Schwarzenegger".

One way to do it would be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MovieId, M.MovieName FROM ACTORS A
INNER JOIN MOVIES M USING (MovieId)
WHERE A.ActorName IN ('Tom Hanks', 'Russell Crowe', 'Arnold Schwarzenegger');
```

Which is perfectly fine, however in my case I might have several more of these conditions on the WHERE clause so I want to find a way to make the MOVIES table the primary table I select from.

What's the best way to query for this?  I'm using Oracle 11g if that matters, but I'm hoping for a standard SQL method.

Comment: Would help if you would show the actual tables you are selecting from ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` or `IN` subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM MOVIES m
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ACTORS a
    WHERE a.MovieId = m.MovieId
    AND a.ActorName IN ('Tom Hanks', 'Russell Crowe', 'Arnold Schwarzenegger')
)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM MOVIES m
WHERE m.MovieId IN 
(
    SELECT a.MovieId
    FROM ACTORS a
    WHERE a.ActorName IN ('Tom Hanks', 'Russell Crowe', 'Arnold Schwarzenegger')
)
```

Comment: Awesome!  I'm actually kinda embarassed I didn't think of this myself, I think I can't code on an empty stomach.

Comment: The above SQL will not work. Text literals must be enclosed in single quotes like this: `'Tom Hanks'`

Comment: Yep. I copied the initial condition :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you should have a 3rd table implementing the n:m relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
 movie_id int primary key
,moviename text
-- more fields
);

CREATE TABLE actor (
 actor_id int primary key
,actorname text
-- more fields
);

CREATE TABLE movieactor (
 movie_id int references movie(movie_id)
,actor_id int references actor(actor_id)
,CONSTRAINT movieactor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id)
);
```

Then you select like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.movie_id, m.moviename
  FROM movie m 
  JOIN movieactor ma USING (movie_id)
  JOIN actor a USING (actor_id)
 WHERE a.actorname IN ('Tom Hanks', 'Russell Crowe', 'Arnold Schwarzenegger');
```

Note, that text literals are enclose in **single quotes**!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is costly. It's better to avoid `DISTINCT` if it's possible.

Comment: Here you can chose between `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` and `WHERE m.MovieId IN (subselect)`. Run a test to see which is faster. I just ran a test on PostgreSQL v9.0 (not Oracle!) with a couple of thousand rows and all three variants took about the same time. It very much depends on the details. Maybe Bogdan speaks from experience with SQL-Server? Each RDBMS performs differently.

Comment: Each RDBMS is different. I agree. Some RDBMS can have a better QueryOptimizer than others. Or not. See item 4 from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers/621891#621891).