# Why does this select for update example work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, data-integrity

I'm running some simple scripts to test possible solutions for an integrity problem I'm solving. Suppose I have a table `my_table`

```
|foo     |
|1       |
```

And I have these two snippets:

```
// db_slow.php
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_playground;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
echo 'starting transaction<br />';
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->query('select * from my_table for update');
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo 'count tables: ', count($rows), '<br />';
if (count($rows) == 1) {
    sleep(10);
    $db->query('insert into my_table(foo) VALUES(2)');
}
$db->commit();
echo 'done';

// db_fast.php
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_plyaground;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
echo 'starting transaction<br />';
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->query('select * from my_table for update');
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo 'count tables: ', count($rows), '<br />';
if (count($rows) == 1) {
    $db->query('insert into my_table(foo) VALUES(3)');
}
$db->commit();
echo 'done';
```

`db_slow.php` has a 10 second delay to simulate a race condition.

As I understand, `select ... for update` locks all rows it selects. If I run `db_slow` then `db_fast`, `db_fast` also has a 10 second delay, as it's waiting for `db_slow` as I expect.

However, what I don't get is this is the output:

```
// db_slow.php
starting transaction
count tables: 1
done

// db_fast.php
starting transaction
count tables: 2
done
```

And `my_table`

```
|foo      |
|1        |
|2        |
```

---

As I understand, `select ... for update` locks all rows that are selected for that transaction. So this is what I expect:

1. db_slow: select row 1 and lock it
2. db_slow: see that it's only 1 row and wait
3. db_fast: try to select row 1, see that it's locked, wait
4. db_slow: insert row with '2'
5. db_fast: continues because row 1 is unlocked
6. db_fast: only selected 1 row, so it inserts '3'
7. End up with `foo: 1, 2, 3`

The output and delay described above seems to confirm steps 1, 2, 3, 4. It seems like `db_fast` is running select after trying to obtain a lock? I thought it would select the one row, then lock or wait.

---

Somewhat related question:

When I run this with `select ... lock in share mode` I end up with

```
// db_slow.php
starting transaction
count tables: 1
done

// db_fast.php
starting transaction
count tables: 1
done
```

And `my_table`

```
|foo      |
|1        |
|3        |
```

Why is `db_slow` not inserting a row '2' even when it thinks there's only 1 row in the table (the condition to insert a row)?

Comment: is `for update` supposed to be in your code somewhere?

Comment: one connection is to my_playground and the other is to adrian_playground_alpha - typo?

Comment: @sgroves Holy crap, tried `lock in share mode` earlier but forgot to change it back. That's embarassing, but a similar thing is happening when I change it to `for update`. @Alden sorry fixed it, they are running on the same database, got multiple scripts and forgot to fix all the inconsistencies pasting here

Comment: Hmmm this is interesting, I would expect the output to be 1, 2, not just 1, 3. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` blocks fast from reading until slow is done, so fast should see count of 2.

Comment: For your question regarding shared mode, did you get any errors? From your output, it looks like both scripts counted only 1 row. They should've both sent their insert statements. Something else is rolling back db_slow's changes. There should be an error message.

Comment: @JohnTseng ah, set it to exception mode and started getting `Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`. I'm not quite sure why this is though, I'll check up on the docs...

Comment: I highly recommend you read up on transaction isolation levels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: Also the section on insert in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html tells you why the inserts deadlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expected behavior is a little off. Before db_slow commits, all rows in the table are locked. After it commits, there are two rows. db_fast is unblocked when db_slow commits. Hence, the behavior is:

1. db_slow: select row 1 and lock it
2. db_slow: see that it's only 1 row and wait
3. db_fast: try to select row 1, see that it's locked, wait
4. db_slow: insert row with '2'
5. db_slow: commit
6. db_fast: unblocked and reads 2 rows
7. db_fast: doesn't do anything
8. End up with foo: 1, 2

Comment: Regarding steps 3 and 6; so if it fails to obtain a lock, it reruns the whole query after it waits gets it? I would expect it only to ensure it has the updated values for the rows it originally expected. But if this is the case it makes sense

Comment: @Raekye The query is blocked from executing when it waits. The actual behavior is not that it *reruns the whole query*, but that it *continues* the original query. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. You cannot divide the table up into parts. Under normal (not read uncommitted) situations, you don't get behaviors like "updated values for rows it originally expected". The point of SQL is that the whole transaction is *atomic*. It would not be atomic of it only reads what it expected should have been there.

Comment: @Raekye I find it easier to reason about transaction isolation level serializable. Although there's a difference in meaning, in this case, there is no difference, so let us suppose that it is serializable. In serializable, there exists an order where one query is done first before the second one begins. In your case, the behavior is that db_slow is completely committed before db_fast starts.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your explanations - and I'll definitely do the reading

Comment: @Raekye Glad to know you are trying to learn about why this stuff is working rather than just slapping SERIALIZABLE on all your queries. =)