# How do I link an Account table with an Order table in MS Access 2013?

Tags: database, windows, ms-access

I'm working on building relationships between my tables. I am not sure if I am doing this the most efficient way or not. Seems to work in my head.

What I have is a simple account set-up that consists of just an email and a time-stamped order number.

What I would like Access to do is automatically insert this information across different tables so the user doesn't have to retype them over on every form.

Here is the relationship table I have now:
[image]

This way the email account and order number match across the tables for keeping the information linked. I have added a button on the forms that `save` and `openForm` but I can't find an option that will auto-insert data.

---

EDIT

I have taken advice and trying to Normalize the tables. Still not sure how I can link them together. How can I group that entire order with that one customer?

Comment: You should normalize your database.  See "Normalize" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers/621891#621891

Comment: @AstraBear Hmmm... I read through that link. I could get this down to two tables Account and Order respectively. I think the main thing I am failing to understand is how do I link the User Account with their Order? I havent done much testing because I am still learning and building at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start:

Make Account table with fields: id, name, email (say)

Have Order table with fields: id, accountId, orderAmount (say)

Make Order.accountId a foreign key linked to Account.id

When you query do something like

select Account.*, Order.* from Account inner join Order on Account.id = Order.accountId