# What is query in my sql to delete multiple records?

Tags: mysql

```
//this is my query for single deletion of record.
  public void deleteEmpDetails(int emp_Id){
         String sql="delete from EmpDetails where emp_Id="+emp_Id;
         JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
         jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
     }
```

Will u please tell me wat is query for multiple rows deletion.Please give me the solution.

Comment: Did you try to search something?

Comment: Use a predicate (read: WHERE) condition that matches multiple records .. and for the love of all programmers, please [use a prepared statement / placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621884/database-development-mistakes-made-by-application-developers/621891#621891).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code,

```
  public void deleteEmpDetails(int emp_Id){
         String sql="delete from EmpDetails where emp_Id IN "+emp_Id;
         JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
         jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
  }
```

Comment: where are you using input parameter to the method?

Comment: I need take emp_Id entered dynamically?

Comment: is `emp_Id` is `array`...??

Comment: than what type of multiple record you want to delete other than emp_Id??

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from EmpDetails where emp_Id in (1, 2, ...)
```